# Trailing zeroes in PHP

Tags: php

I have a value `$rating` that is between 0.00 and 10.00.

I need to add trailing zeroes to numbers like 3.70 (which is 3.7) and 5.00 (which is 5). Do I need some kind of if statement too to check what value `$rating` is and then do some kind of `str_pad`? I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `number_format` function

```
echo number_format(5, 2);    // returns 5.00
echo number_format(5.2, 2);  // returns 5.20
echo number_format(5.24, 2); // returns 5.24
```

Comment: Very easy solution, thank you. I'll accept when it allows me too.

Answer (score 0):

Try number_format, something like this:

```
number_format((float)$yourNumber, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Damn, I meant trailing zeroes.

Comment: But you see question what he asked, he want 5.7 to become 5.70 etc. This is what it will do.

Comment: Edited, apologise for that.